# Combine two independent predictions of 55% and 65%

Tags: probability, self-study

Quant developer interview question:

> There are two price prediction models, one with accuracy 55%, another with accuracy 65%, both predict price is gonna go up, what's the probability that price is gonna go up? Please provide detailed answer.

One can assume two predictions are independent.

Comment: I put [tag:self-study] tag here because this is a textbook-style problem copy-pasted from elsewhere. The policy of this forum is to provide "helpful hints".

Comment: How did you arrive at these estimates, logistic regression?  What sample size was used to fit the models?  Did you get the predictions by test on data not used for fitting?

Comment: With what probability do the models predict that the price will increase? This seems like a good place to care about model output probabilities and proper scoring rules. (Where are Harrell and Kolassa...?) I also would consider the probability that the asset increases in value. This is a different problem if the asset usually loses value but has the occasional major increase in value than if the asset gains and loses value with the same frequency.

Comment: i am not sure to understand why the calculation of this probability answers the question?
can somebody elaborate?
we are supposed to compute the following probability:
Probability(price is up/ model 1 and model 2 predict that the price is up)

Answer (score 1):

A simple answer here.

We construct random variable X representing correctness of model 1. X=1 if model 1 is correct, 0 otherwise. Similarly we define Y for model 2.

Consider Pr(model 1 is correct and model 2 is correct|both are correct or both are wrong), since we know they give same prediction, thus we have this condition of both correct or both wrong.

It's easy to calculate the probability: $\frac{0.55*0.65}{0.55*0.65+0.45*0.35}=0.6942$.

Thus with 0.6942 probability, the price grows up.

Answer (score 0):

This could be considered an example of aggregate data meta-analysis.

Before pooling the two estimates, you need to provide also the variability in such effect estimates with a standard error or equivalent.

Then you can simply perform pooling with fixed effect inverse variance weighting.